# Using LaTex labels in matplotlib and GUI built with PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pyqt5

I have built a simple GUI using Qt Designer, `PyQt5`, and `matplotlib` to plot some functions that are in a list on the GUI that the user can choose (e.g. sin(x), e^x, etc.). The GUI works fine and I have been using it in a Jupyter notebook, except for getting the labels of the plots, which I want to be in LaTeX. I can set the labels, title, etc. as one normally would in `matplotlib`, but LaTeX labels do not work. I have tried

```
from matplotlib import rc
...
mpl.rc('text', usetex = True)
mpl.rc('font', family = 'serif'
...
```

but when I try to set the labels (such as `ax1f1.set_xlabel(r'\textbf{Time (s)}')`) I get the following error:

```
TimeoutError: Lock error: Matplotlib failed to acquire the following lock file:
    C:\Users\Owner\.matplotlib\tex.cache\3bbc0f8d536770a62891b7cc8788c317.tex.matplotlib-lock
This maybe due to another process holding this lock file.  If you are sure no
other Matplotlib process is running, remove this file and try again.
```

I suspect that the error is caused by the GUI file that I am importing into my Jupyter session, where I also have the following import statements:

```
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
```

Does this mean that I can't use both the backend functionality of `matplotlib` and `rc` at the same time?

The code I used for the GUI is here:

```
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)

Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow = loadUiType('window.ui')


class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow) :
    def __init__(self, ) :
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.fig_dict = {}
        
        self.mplfigs.itemClicked.connect(self.changefig)
        
        fig = Figure()
        self.addmpl(fig)
        
    def addfig(self, name, fig) :
        self.fig_dict[name] = fig
        self.mplfigs.addItem(name)
        
    def addmpl(self, fig) :
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        self.mplvl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas,
                                         self.mplwindow,
                                         coordinates=True)
        self.mplvl.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        
    def changefig(self, item) :
        text = item.text()
        self.remove_mpl()
        self.addmpl(self.fig_dict[text])
        
    def remove_mpl(self, ) :
        self.mplvl.removeWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.close()
        self.mplvl.removeWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.toolbar.close()
        
    def closeEvent(self, event) :
        QApplication.quit()
        
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    import numpy as np
    
    fig1 = Figure()
    ax1f1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
    ax1f1.plot(np.random.rand(5))
    
    fig2 = Figure()
    ax1f2 = fig2.add_subplot(121)
    ax1f2.plot(np.random.rand(5))
    ax2f2 = fig2.add_subplot(122)
    ax2f2.plot(np.random.rand(10))
    
    fig3 = Figure()
    ax1f3 = fig3.add_subplot(111)
    ax1f3.pcolormesh(np.random.rand(20,20))
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.addfig('One plot', fig1)
    main.addfig('Two plots', fig2)
    main.addfig('Pcolormesh', fig3)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Have you tried clearing tex.cache as indicated [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/text/usetex.html#troubleshooting)?

Comment: @Heike that seems to have worked. Thanks!